# Custom Event Handler not invoked

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a tab item whose content is a custom UserControl. I want to notify the main window whenever a tab item is removed from the tab control. I want to raise an event in the UserControl and have the main window handles the event. Here is my code

In the main window:

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent CloseTabEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "CloseTab", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MainWindow));

private void CloseTab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("a tab item was removed");
}
```

In the tab control:

```
RaiseEvent( new RoutedEventArgs(MainWindow.CloseTabEvent));
```

When I ran the code, there wasn't "a tab item is removed" being printed out. What is the right way to make it work?

Comment: Hasn't your tab control some default EventHandler that you can exploit for your custom event?

Comment: I see there is a ControlRemoved in windows forms. I use wpf and couldn't find an event handler that suits my need.

Comment: Are you missing something in your code? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288.aspx

Comment: I don't know. I read that but didn't think I need the CLR accessors (because the TabItems were created progmatically, not through xaml)

Comment: I think, in this case, there is no sense in this event - `CloseTabEvent`. Because, `RaiseEvent` necessary most invoke, somewhere, and it will be a close event of TabItem, for example - `Button.Click`.

Comment: Can you show us how you set the handler?

Comment: @ninja, I thought the 2nd line of my code: private void CloseTab(... is my handler, which is registered in line 1 to an event CloseTabEvent.

Comment: No, you are wrong. You have to set the handler in XAML on Window. <Window local:MyApplication:CloseTab="OnCloseTabMethod">...</Window>